# To split by date and event columns

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to split by date and event columns. It is impossible to search for ". " some lines contain multiple sentences ending with ". " Also, some lines don't start with dates. The idea of ​​the script was to use a regexp to find lines starting with the fragment "one or two numbers, space, letters, period, space" and then replace "point, space" with a rare character, for example, "@". If the line does not start with this fragment, then add "@" to the beginning. Then this array can be easily divided into two parts by this symbol ("@") and written to the sheet.

Unfortunately, something went wrong today. I came across the fact that `match(re)` is always `null`. I ask for help in composing the correct regular expression and solving the problem.

Original text:

> 1 June. Astronomers report narrowing down the source of Fast Radio
> Bursts (FRBs).  It may now plausibly include "compact-object mergers
> and magnetars arising from normal core collapse supernovae".[3][4]
>
> The existence of quark cores in neutron stars is confirmed by Finnish
> researchers.[5][6][7]
>
> 3 June. Researchers show that compared to rural populations urban red
> foxes (pictured) in London are mirroring patterns of domestication
> similar to domesticated dogs, as they adapt to their city
> environment.[21]
>
> The discovery of the oldest and largest structure in
> the Maya region, a 3,000-year-old pyramid-topped platform Aguada
> Fénix, with LiDAR technology is reported.
>
> 17 June. Physicists at the XENON dark matter research facility report
> an excess of 53 events, which may hint at the existence of
> hypothetical Solar axions.

Desired result:

[image]

Code:

```
function replace() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  // const range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lr - 1);
  const range = sheet.getRange(100, 4, 5);
  const arr = range.getValues();
  const newArr = [];
  const re = new RegExp("^([0-9]{1,2}\s[a-z]+\.)\s");

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const match = arr[i][0].match(re);
    if (match == null) {
      let newEntry = "@" + arr[i];
      newArr.push(newEntry);
    } else {
      // let newEntry = "#" + arr[i];
      // newArr.push(newEntry);
    }
  }
  // range.offset(0,1).setValues(newArr);
  //  console.log(newArr);
}
```

Comment: Note the regex set with the regular string literal needs proper escaping. It must be either `new RegExp("^([0-9]{1,2}\\s[a-z]+\\.)\\s")` or `/^([0-9]{1,2}\s[a-z]+\.)\s/`

Comment: Mama Mia! You are absolutely right! I can't sit at the comp for days. Thank you.

Comment: The question of how to replace "." with "@" (part of the code inside "else {}") remained unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function breakapart() {
  const ms = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Data Sheet
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//Output Sheet
  osh.clearContents();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let oA = [];
  vs.forEach(p => {
    let f = p.split(/[. ]/);
    if (!isNaN(f[0]) && ms.includes(f[1])) {
      let s = p.slice(0, p.indexOf('.'));
      let t = p.slice(p.indexOf('.')+2);
      oA.push([s, t]);
    } else {
      oA.push(['',p]);
    }
  });
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the working script! You have taken a different approach. Unfortunately, this produces a slightly unexpected result. [link](https://ibb.co/rGGrTCc)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that link so I'm not going to following it

Comment: Sorry. There is a screenshot of the result. At first I saw that there was duplicate lines. Then I realized that this was due to the fact that in my original sheet there were columns not only with the original text, but also with the desired result. When I removed those columns, everything worked great right away. Thank you!